# Display Data in unified shell (sap.ui.unified.shell)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm an intern and i'm working on sapui5 project, i want to display some data into unifiedshell specifically in  but it always "no data" and i'm sure that the code where i call the data is correct , please i need help 
there is shell.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="opensap.shell.controller.shell.shell"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns="sap.m"
class="viewPadding">
    <u:Shell
        id="myShell"
        icon="{/logo}">
        <u:headItems>
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                tooltip="Configuration"
                icon="sap-icon://menu2"
                press="handlePressConfiguration" />
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                tooltip="Home"
                icon="sap-icon://home"
                visible="false"
                press="handlePressHome" />
        </u:headItems>
        <u:headEndItems>
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                icon="sap-icon://log"
                tooltip="Logoff"
                press="handleLogoffPress" />
        </u:headEndItems>
        <u:user>
            <u:ShellHeadUserItem
                image="sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                username="Karl Mustermann"
                press="handleUserItemPressed" />
        </u:user>
        <u:search>
            <SearchField
                search="handleSearchPressed"/>
        </u:search>
         <u:paneContent>
              <List id="product" headerText="Products" items="{/ProductSet}">
            <items>
                <StandardListItem
                    title="{ProductID}"

                    />
            </items>
        </List>
            </u:paneContent>


    </u:Shell>
```

Comment: No data indicates that there are either no data, your binding is wrong or data is not loaded. Impossible to answer without more information. It is definitely no problem of the Unified Shell

Comment: have i to declare data as a namespace ? if you have an exemple may you show it to me ?

Comment: <List id="product" headerText="Products" items="{/ProductSet}">
ProductSet it's the model which i want to display

Comment: Please provide the part where you instantiate the model.